# isTextPresent fails all the time in Selenium test. Not sure if I am doing anything wrong

Tags: java, selenium

I have this little piece of code that just checks for a particular text at a location on the page and if that text is found, it will check for something else..Here is the snippet:

if (!selenium.isTextPresent("//div[contains(concat('',@class,''),'contentLg')]/h2")) {
                        System.out.println("The About Us text is not present");
        }
        else {
            verifyEquals(aboutText, "//*[@class='content contentLg']/p[3]");
        }

Here is the generated output that I am trying to grab the text "About Us" from. I am trying to see if the page has "About Us" text (which is in

### tag). If there is, just match one of the "p" tag with predefined text:

```
 <!-- MAIN CONTENT CONTAINER -->
```

About Us

```
        <p><span class="faqQuestion">About The Site</span><br>
        this is about the site</p> 

        <p>test one two three</p>

        <p>this test test test test test test</p>

        <br>

        <p><span class="faqQuestion">About Company</span><br>
        This is about the company</p> 

        <p>fafasdfsafasdfafasfasfasasfasfasfafsasf</p> 

        <p>afasfasdfasdffafffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</p> 

        <br>

        <p><span class="faqQuestion">Helping Businesses</span><br>
        Helping business
        <a href="/businesses.asp">click here</a> to learn more.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I wrote in a CustomSelenium class that extends DefaultSelenium.

```
public boolean waitForTextPresent(final String text, long timeout) {
    Wait wait = new Wait() {

        @Override
        public boolean until() {
            try {
                return CustomSelenium.this.isTextPresent(text);
            } catch (SeleniumException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    try {
        wait.wait("Error: text " + text + " not present in the page", timeout, 50);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    } catch (WaitTimedOutException e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Just call this before you call isTextPresent. This is [a Selenium bug](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SRC-261).